# Multiple or single Compound index

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say you have a table with `id,a,b,c,d,e,f,g` with around 1 million rows. Then one could make a query with multiple `WHERE ...AND...AND...etc` conditions in multiple combinations. 
That is for example `a AND b AND e` or `a AND f AND g` or `e AND f AND g`.

So to account for all combinations, you would have to create multiple compound indexes  but what if `a,b,c,d,e,f,g` have a range from [1,10] therefore no zero.

Could one simply make a single compound per start variable so `a,b,c,d,e,f,g` and `b,a,c,d,e,f,g` etc.. and the during query time do something like

```
  #b and e have not been chosen
  SELECT * FROM WHERE a=3 AND b!=0 AND c=4 AND d=5 AND e!=0 AND f=1 AND g=9
  #I think you get the logic
```

Could such procedure allow mysql to still use the compound index or do I really need to create all possible combinations of compound indexes.

The end result would reduce the number of indexes to 7 instead of number of left combinations possibles which is way higher than 7.

Comment: This kind of problem is sometimes symptomatic of a lack of normalisation

Comment: It's the simulation of a materialized view in mysql hence the high number of columns.

Comment: Strawberry does have a point of normalization, provided your a-g columns are all same context.  However, if your data is each a-g column is of its own normalized value -- such as in a govt contracts table I worked with.  The root table had links to over 20 individual lookup reference table each normalized to ID.  If you can expand more than generic a-g context, we could provide better clarification and input to your situation.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL will use compound indexes in order if it can.  So if your data represents some taxonomy a single index will do.  Let's say customers can be type either business or personal, and live in a given postal code, and be status premium or regular, then a query like

```
SELECT * FROM customer 
WHERE type = 'business' 
AND postal_code = '12345' 
AND  status = 'premium';
```

would be able to use an index based on a compound key built of `type` + `postal_code` + `status`.  If you didn't know `status`, the index would still be useful.  But if you *only* knew `postal_code` but not `type`, the index would not be used -- order matters.

But I agree with the comment from Strawberry -- this is typically not a problem in a standard relational schema.  It's not unusual to have several foreign keys in a table, but unless you're building a data cube, or some other special design, this problem just isn't one you probably should be having -- certainly not with 7 fields.

But if this is a real problem, consider the value of each potentially indexed field.  If most queries are able to narrow the million rows down to a few thousand using several indexes (compound or not) the final scan may be trivial.  Experiment with `EXPLAIN PLAN` to see at what point it stops mattering for most queries.

The cost of maintaining an index may be trivial ... or not.  In highly tuned transactional systems, a single insert, update, or delete would result in N+1 writes: the one for the row, and the other N for each index.  If you're mostly reading, then this may be fine.  If not, then some combination of compound keys could potentially have some benefit by reducing the number of writes.

But I have been working with relational database for more than a few decades.  Cases where this scenario arises have almost always been resolved by rethinking the schema design; I don't recall a case where a compound key made more sense than multiple indexes in a typical relational and well-normalized schema.